# TaskCanceledException but not due to timeout

Tags: c#

As part of my application I make an HTTP call to another service which has 10 seconds to come back:

```
//only one instance of HttpClient is ever created
client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = 10000;
```

For the call itself, I wrap a stopwatch around it to log the time taken:

```
try 
{
    stopWatch.Reset();
    stopWatch.Start();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url)
    stopWatch.Stop();
}
catch (TaskCanceledException e)
{
    log.Error("Task cancelled after {0} milliseconds", stopWatch.Elapsed)
}
```

What I see from time to time is the logs showing lots of these task cancelled errors, with many of them recorded as having waited for 10 seconds (which is exactly what you would expect).

But I see some which were **not allowed this full time**, instead they threw a TaskCanceledException but after only 1 second, or 5 seconds etc recorded on the stopwatch.

I understand TaskCanceledException is not always caused by the timeout, but what could be cancelling the tasks in this case? Having an understanding of the possibilities given this situation would help.

Comment: Is `client` ever disposed?

Comment: No, client is only instantiated in the constructor and then only has requests placed against it.

Comment: Have you checked the `TaskCanceledException`'s `Message` property to see if it says why the task was canceled?

Comment: Are you making these calls concurrently? `stopWatch` may be being used from multiple threads.

Comment: Yes, I was unable to find anything which suggested the reason:  System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: @FBryant87 if you use the same stopwatch you'll end up with race conditions. One thread could reset it while another tried to "stop" it some time later. Create the stopwatch *inside* your `try` statement instead. After all, it's very cheap - it's only a wrapper around a performance counter

Comment: @FBryant87 post your *full* code too, including the code that creates the stopwatch

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos and PhilK, these are good points, won't the async definitely be a problem as we don't know when a thread will return even once the task times out? Also why does including it in the try solve the race condition?

Comment: @Fbryant87 the stopwatch is only a wrapper that reads the values of a counter. It displays the *difference* between any calls to Start/Restart and stop or whenever you call `Ellapsed`. If you share it, you'll read garbage differences because *one* thread will read the start value stored by *another*. It's llike setting the same `DateTime` global variable to count time differences. Post your code. And create the stopwatch right before your call to `GetAsync`, ie `var stopwatch=Stopwatch.StartNew(); var response = await client.GetAsync(url);stopwatch.Stop();`